# Why this declaration is correct in Java

Tags: java, list, class, interface

I am new to Java and I have a huge confusion here. How is this possible

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

List is an interface and how it can have a ArrayList which is a class.

Comment: you need to learn first oops feature.

Comment: It's called inheritance https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html a basic feature of all object orientated languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of a variable and the type of the object the variable refers to do not need to be the same, so long as the type of the object is *compatible* with the type of the variable. So what does it mean to be compatible?

It means that the object's type has an "is a" relationship with the variable's type. `ArrayList<String>` "is a" `List<String>`, because `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface. That is, `ArrayList` has all of the methods that `List` defines, and declares (by saying `implements List`) that it conforms to the definition of those methods.

This is a fundamental concept in object-oriented programming called [*polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). That is, we can say that there is a thing called a `List`, and we can write code that works with `List`s, without that code knowing that the actual `List`s it's working with are `ArrayList`s or `LinkedList`s or any other *concrete type*.

In this case, it's with an interface, but the same concept applies in object type hierarchies as well. If you have class `Animal`, you might have a more specific subclass (`Dog`). Anything that works with the `Animal` type can work with `Dog`s, because `Dog` *is an* `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Any class can contains its successor, because child class always contents all of parent class and can contain extra data. Example:

```
    class Parent {
    String someField;
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
    //Here we can access someField field
    Long anyAnotherField;
    }
```

In Java there isn't multi-inheritance (class A can extends only one class). But there is a interface and classes can inheritance any number of interfaces. If you see the documentation, you can see, that there is `interface Collection`, `interface List extends Collection`, `class ArrayList implementing List`. So you can put your `ArrayList` in `List<T>`, `List` (without parameter), `Collection`, `Object`(in Java all classes had Object as parent class). (There are many another classes like AbstractList, it's only example)